# React Native Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a big problem with my code at the moment, and I know, there is a lot of request with the same issue as mine. I tried a lot of the solutions, but NOTHING helped.
Maybe someone can help me :)

I get the issue in the Title mentionend:

```
Error: The component for route 'Home' must be a React component. For
example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen'; ... Home: MyScreen, }

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator'; ... Home: MyNavigator, }
```

This is my code in the specified files:

`App.js`

```js
import React from 'react'; import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'; import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Home from './src/Home'; import Profile from './src/Profile';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({ Home: { screen: Home }, Profile: { screen: Profile }, }, { initialRouteName: 'Home', });
const App = createAppContainer(Navigator);

export default App;
```

`Home.js`

```
import React from 'react'; import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home', };
    
    render() {
    
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
    
                <Button
                    title="Go to profile screen"
                    onPress={() => navigate(
                        'Profile', { name: 'Jane' }
                    )}
                />
                
            </View>
        );
    
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' } });
```

`Profile.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: navigation.getParam('name'),
    };
};

render() {

    const { navigate, state } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Hello {state.params.name}</Text>

            <Button
                title="Go to home screen"
                onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
            />

        </View>
    );

}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
}
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help... Same error.

Do you have another Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are having the following structure in your project:

App.js in your project folder. Home.js and Profile.js in the src folder.

App.js (in ./ folder)

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'; 
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; 
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Home from './src/Home'; 
import Profile from './src/Profile';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({ Home: { screen: Home }, Profile: { screen: Profile }, }, { initialRouteName: 'Home', });
const App = createAppContainer(Navigator);

export default App;
```

Home.js (in ./src folder)

```
import React from 'react'; import { StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home', };
    
    render() {
    
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
    
                <Button
                    title="Go to profile screen"
                    onPress={() => navigate(
                        'Profile', { name: 'Jane' }
                    )}
                />
                
            </View>
        );
    
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' } });
```

Profile.js (in ./src folder)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends React.Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: navigation.getParam('name'),
    };
};

render() {

    const { navigate, state } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Hello {state.params.name}</Text>

            <Button
                title="Go to home screen"
                onPress={() => navigate('Home')}
            />

        </View>
    );

}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'
}
});
```

If you place all the files correctly, it will WORK.

**Please click the link below to see the result:**

http://www.createchhk.com/2020_12_30_01_56_22.mp4

Comment: you know `extend React.Component` and `extend Component` with `Component` importing  does the same thing, right?

Comment: named import is always a good practice. Please focus on the 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: i saw, and i assumed that was his mistake on writing this question. It will not run otherwise, dont you think?

Comment: You are for sure right. Just make sure he did not actually "merge" the codes.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help... Same error.

Do you have another Solution?

Comment: I have revised my answer. Just make sure that your screens are placed properly in the folder (1) App.js in the root of your project , and (2) Home.js and Profile.js in the src folder. and the codes should work. Please see the link in my answer which show that there is NO ERROR in your codes (I have made a screen recording to show the result)